# Time passing faster now as compared to 50 years (or 1000yrs) back ?

Tags: time, perception

I asked 200 people (who include my friends and family members in age group of 15 to 70 years living in cities) how they feel about time ? Do they feel that the time is passing faster as compared to when they were child? 
95% of those people say that now a days time is passing much faster than lets say 50 years back when they were younger.

Is this an established fact and can be explained using theory of relativity or any other law that time (may be on average) is passing faster *now*  as compared to lets say 50 yrs or may be 1000 yrs back?
Or is it only a subjective experience?

Comment: This is not about the physics of time at all, It's about the psychology of *feeling* time!

Comment: It is called aging.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with aging. The more the person gets older, the more they receive outer impressions automaticaly/roboticaly. A child takes in impressions much much more consciously. When/IF a man can take impressions in always consciously - time "almost" stops...When you look around at other people you see nothing but totaly predictable robots, people in deep sleep/illusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not physics at all, but I think it can most readily be explained by the fact that people generally experience time as moving faster as they get older.

This is because as we age, things that happened a year ago don't seem so distance, because we can also remember things that happened 10 years ago. If you were only 5 years old, something that happened a year ago happened a 5th of your life ago - a huge amount of time compared with your current lifespan.

As far as I know, there is no law that says time passes any slower or faster depending on the age of the (universe) earth.

Edit: I have just seen this, a much better answer to the question than mine. [Perception of time as a function of age](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/129/perception-of-time-as-a-function-of-age/) (thanks jinawee)

Comment: Do you think there is some additional effect related to comparing the total amount of memories one has to some kind of "amount of current memories"? Hmm... just a vague idea...